# How to show document file into iframe return from href action lnk?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an index page index.cshtml.Which is showing a list of document file and with beside an iframe.I want to show document file into iframe when i click any one of a list.But when i click anyone of a document list shows another page.

index

```
<table>
                        @*<th>File Name</th>*@
                        @foreach (var file in Model)
                {
                                    <li>
                                        @*<a href="#"id="fileId" data-id="@file.Id">@file.Name</a>*@
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document", new { Id=file.Id})">@file.Name</a>
                                     </li>    
                    <br />
                }
                    </table>
<div id="frame" class="panel-default" >
                <div id="frame" class="panel" >
                    <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document", new { Id=@Model.First().Id})" width="870px" height="450px"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller

```
  [HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult GetFile(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
            Id = 4;
        string fileName = _manager.FileNameSearch(Id);
        string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return File(fs, "application/pdf");            
    }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="frame" class="panel">
<iframe id="iframe" src="@Model.Url" width="870px" height="450px" name="iframe"></iframe>
</div>    

 <li>
<a href="@Url.Action("GetFile", "Document", new { Id = Model.Id })" target="iframe">@Model.Name</a>
```